# Change Adobe PDF printer preferences

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe

Hi I want to change the settings highlited in yellow using python, I wrote this code to access the perferances but I don't know what I should do next to change these settings, any idea?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJGS9.png)

```
import win32print
import win32con

# set the printer name
printer_name = "Adobe PDF"

# get the handle to the printer
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

# get the current printer preferences
data = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2)
```

Comment: these are the data returned by win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2)
{'pServerName': None, 'pPrinterName': 'Adobe PDF', 'pShareName': '', 'pPortName': 'Documents\\*.pdf', 'pDriverName': 'Adobe PDF Converter', 'pComment': '', 'pLocation': '', 'pDevMode': <PyDEVMODEW object at 0x00000233F5CD6D60>, 'pSepFile': '', 'pPrintProcessor': 'winprint', 'pDatatype': 'RAW', 'pParameters': '', 'pSecurityDescriptor': <PySECURITY_DESCRIPTOR object at 0x00000233F5C16630>, 'Attributes': 4672, 'Priority': 1, 'DefaultPriority': 0, 'StartTime': 0, 'UntilTime': 0, 'Status': 0, 'cJobs': 0, 'AveragePPM': 0}